# How to Present a particular View Controller when the application Becomes active from background on IOS Swift App

Tags: ios, swift

I need to present the Main Screen of my app, whenever it becomes active from background so that I can access the users current location. my app only access user location from the main Screen and it will not keep updating the location after that.

How can I accomplish this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, please, [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back with some code for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can load the main controller or the home controller from the AppDelegate using the function:

`func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}`

Implement the below code inside applicationDidBecomeActive

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourVCToPresent = "MainScreenController" //change name as per storyboard ID
    let rootViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: yourVCToPresent) as UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This will set your Main controller as root and present it, when application becomes active.

Also, have a look at how location services work with appropriate user permissions and implement accordingly. [Location services guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location)

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) is not available anymore. How should I use it in sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) method. I try to copy paste the same code in there without any luck. Thanks